# I am trying to load variables in an array

Tags: php, arrays, api, curl

I am using an api that returns an array, I am trying to get set the variables of each condition that i need but cannot figure it out.

Here is the array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [sl_translate] => description,descriptionPlain,category
        [id] => 65392
        [slug] => crystal-coma
        [name] => Crystal Coma
        [symbol] => Crc
        [category] => Sativa
        [description] => <p class="p1">Crystal Coma is a rare sativa-dominant hybrid from California that induces deep, trance-like effects. Its name foreshadows the debilitating relaxation to come, a long-lasting calm that shuts off mental overactivity. Pastel green breaks through this sativa&rsquo;s thick blanket of crystal trichomes that contributes to its staggeringly high THC content of up to 26 percent. Crystal Coma&rsquo;s genetics are long lost, but myth has it that the origins lie in <a href="http://www.leafly.com/indica/cheese"><span class="s1">Cheese</span></a> and <a href="http://www.leafly.com/sativa/skunk-1"><span class="s1">Skunk #1</span></a>. Anxiety, PTSD, pain, and sleeplessness are no match for Crystal Coma&rsquo;s potency, a medicine that is highly recommended for nighttime use.&nbsp;Crystal Coma took 3rd place in&nbsp;the 2014 L.A. Cannabis Cup.</p>

        [descriptionPlain] => Crystal Coma is a rare sativa-dominant hybrid from California that induces deep, trance-like effects. Its name foreshadows the debilitating relaxation to come, a long-lasting calm that shuts off mental overactivity. Pastel green breaks through this sativa&rsquo;s thick blanket of crystal trichomes that contributes to its staggeringly high THC content of up to 26 percent. Crystal Coma&rsquo;s genetics are long lost, but myth has it that the origins lie in Cheese and Skunk #1. Anxiety, PTSD, pain, and sleeplessness are no match for Crystal Coma&rsquo;s potency, a medicine that is highly recommended for nighttime use.&nbsp;Crystal Coma took 3rd place in&nbsp;the 2014 L.A. Cannabis Cup.

        [aka] => 
        [rating] => 5
        [reviewCount] => 6
        [flavors] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Lemon
                        [score] => 40
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Pungent
                        [score] => 26.25
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Cheese
                        [score] => 20
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Flowery
                        [score] => 20
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Skunk
                        [score] => 20
                    )

            )

        [effects] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Euphoric
                        [score] => 105
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Relaxed
                        [score] => 92.5
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Energetic
                        [score] => 85
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Uplifted
                        [score] => 78.75
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Happy
                        [score] => 65
                    )

            )

        [symptoms] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Depression
                        [score] => 51.25
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Stress
                        [score] => 51.25
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Pain
                        [score] => 38.75
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Fatigue
                        [score] => 26.25
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Lack of Appetite
                        [score] => 25
                    )

            )

        [conditions] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => ADD/ADHD
                        [score] => 32.5
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Anxiety
                        [score] => 32.5
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => PTSD
                        [score] => 32.5
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Asthma
                        [score] => 20
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Arthritis
                        [score] => 6.25
                    )

            )

        [negatives] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Dizzy
                        [score] => 6.25
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Dry Eyes
                        [score] => 6.25
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Dry Mouth
                        [score] => 6.25
                    )

            )

        [articlesAvailable] => 1
        [photos] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [uploaded] => /Date(1398397718127)/
                        [thumb] => http://leafly.blob.core.windows.net/reviews/crystal-coma_100x100_255e.jpg
                        [fullsize] => http://d3odcnigi1nnzz.cloudfront.net/cdn/strain-photo/132654/b/crystal-coma_825x550_4e1f.jpg
                    )

            )

        [popularCities] => Array
            (
                [0] => Colorado Springs,CO
                [1] => Vancouver,BC
                [2] => North Palm Springs,CA
                [3] => Temecula,CA
                [4] => Torrance,CA
            )

        [permalink] => http://www.leafly.com/sativa/crystal-coma
        [starImage] => //d3odcnigi1nnzz.cloudfront.net/stars/5/240
        [testGraph] => 
        [weakDescription] => 
        [parents] => Array
            (
            )

        [growInfo] => Array
            (
                [difficulty] => 
                [preferredMedium] => 
                [floweringDays] => 0
                [outdoorFinish] => 
                [height] => 
                [averageYield] => 
                [environment] => 
                [growNotes] => 
            )

    )

)
```

I am trying to get the effects, symptoms, negatives and popular cities extracted out of the array.

here is what I have tried so far:

```
$strain =  $_REQUEST['strain'];
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://data.leafly.com/strains/".$strain); //change the strain dynamically of course for your app
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('APP_ID:'.$appID,'APP_KEY:'.$appKEY));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//Clean it into an php array object and set var
$cleaned_response = array(json_decode($output,true));
//Set Variables
foreach($cleaned_response as $i)
{
   $titles=$i['name'];
   $category = $i['category'];
   $description = $i['description'];
   $rating = $i['rating'];
   //Convert this array to variables
   foreach($i['effects'] as $a=>$value){
            $effects =  '<li>'. $a[$value] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;    
        }

   foreach($i['symptoms'] as $a=>$value){
            $symptoms =  '<li>'. $a[$value] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;   
        }

   foreach($i['negatives'] as $a=>$value){
            $negatives =  '<li>'. $a[$value] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;  
        }

   foreach($i['popularCities'] as $a=>$value){
            $popularCities =  '<li>'. $a[$value] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;  
        }
}
```

but it is not returning the results.

Comment: Is this the whole file or code goes on?

Comment: `$a[$value]` is incorrect. $a at the point is the **KEY**, not an array itself.

Comment: Kypros, it is the whole code.  I actually just moved them down to where they needed to be then changed the variables from `$a[$value'];` to `$value['name'];` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one example

```
 foreach($i['effects'] as $a=>$value){
            $effects =  '<li>'. $a[$value] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;    
        }
```

That is an incorrect loop to extract effects. `$a` is the key of each effect and `$value` is the array that contains name and score. So you cant say `$a[$value];`. It should be

```
  foreach($i['effects'] as $a=>$value){
            $effects. =  '<li>'. $value['score'] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;     // or name
                                ^
        }
```

fix that for all your loops and you're good

Answer (score 1):

Two problems i can see at first look in this code:

1. IF this is your whole file, you are not outputting the values in any way in order for them to display to the browser,
2. You are overwriting the variables each time instead of appending to them (use `.=`)
3. You are using the `key`=>`value` pair wrong, ie to take the name of the recipe you should do something similar to:

   ```
   $effects = "";
   foreach($i['effects'] as $a=>$value){
      $effects .=  '<li>'. $value['name'] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;    
   }

   echo $effects;
   ```

Although this is untested code, it should work as `$value` inside the loop is still an array and you'll need to add the `name` or other proper index to get the needed value.

Answer (score 0):

define variables out side the main foreach loop

Note that `[popularCities]` is not a multidimentional array

```
$effects = $symptoms = $negatives = $popularCities = "";

//foreach($cleaned_response as $i)

   foreach($i['effects'] as $a=>$value){
            $effects .=  '<li>'. $value['name'] .'</li>';  
            $effects .=  '<li>'. $value['score'] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;  
        }

   foreach($i['symptoms'] as $a=>$value){
            $symptoms .=  '<li>'. $value['name'] .'</li>';  
            $symptoms .=  '<li>'. $value['score'] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;   
        }

   foreach($i['negatives'] as $a=>$value){
            $negatives .=  '<li>'. $value['name'] .'</li>';  
            $negatives .=  '<li>'. $value['score'] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;    
        }

   foreach($i['popularCities'] as $a=>$value){
            $popularCities .=  '<li>'. $value .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;  
        }
```